# Cannot mupliply Int by 2 in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of digits presented like strings - `["1", "2", "3"]`

my goal is to return back the multiplied array.

```
func multiplyInts(_ num: Int) -> Array<Any> {
    var arr = Array(String(num))
    var resultArr = [Int]()
    for i in 0...arr.count {
        var strIn = String(arr[i])
        var numIn = Int(strIn) * 2 // here's the error
        resultArr.append(numIn)
    }
    return Array(resultArr)
}
```

I'm converting String to Int and multiplying this number by two, but my program won't compile and says error.

Comment: Does multiplying an int by 3 work?

Comment: You are playing a Russian roulette.  You don't know if a string is actually a number.  That's why it's optional.

Comment: "// here's the error" And what's the error? You might not understand it, but we might help teach you how to read it, in case of tomorrow you see a similar one...

Comment: but if I unwrap it as my XCode suggests me I get an: Fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are at least two displayed errors and a fatal mistake.

- The return type is wrong
- `Int(strIn)` returns an optional, you have to (safely) unwrap it
- `0...arr.count` will cause a crash, it must be `0..<arr.count`

Further

- the parameter type should be `[String]`
- Creating an `Array` from an `Array` is redundant.

Long story short: To convert a string array to an Int array and multiply each element by two you can use this

```
func multiplyInts(_ array: [String]) -> [Int] {
    return array.compactMap(Int.init).map{$0 * 2}
}
    
let result = multiplyInts(["1", "2", "3"]) // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code may be useful for you

```swift
func multiplyInts(_ num: Int) -> Array<Any> {
    let arr = Array(String(num))
    var resultArr = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<arr.count {
        let strIn = String(arr[i])
        if let intNum = Int(strIn) {
            let numIn = intNum * 2
            resultArr.append(numIn)
        }
    }
    return Array(resultArr)
}

print(multiplyInts(123)) // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map`.

```
func multiplyInts(_ num: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    num.map { $0 * 2 }
}
```

Example:

```
print(multiplyInts([1, 2, 3]))
// Prints: [2, 4, 6]
```